# pytorch: loss.backward out of memory for the second batch

Tags: memory, pytorch

I am learning seq2seq model using https://github.com/keon/seq2seq. I have successfully run the original project. Then, I want to train my-self translation model.

For myself data, the following code is OK. But for second batch, `out of memory` is reported for loss.backward. The second batch data is smaller than the first one.

```
    src, trg = src.cuda().T, trg.cuda().T
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model(src, trg)
    loss = F.nll_loss(output[1:].view(-1, vocab_size),
                           trg[1:].contiguous().view(-1),
                           ignore_index=pad)
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), grad_clip)
    optimizer.step()
    total_loss += loss.data.item()
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

For batch size = 16, the above code is OK for first batch, and `out of memory` is reported at loss.backward for second batch.

The used gpu for first batch is:

```
2233 MB src, trg = src.cuda().T, trg.cuda().T
2331 MB output = model(src, trg)
4772 MB loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
6471 MB optimizer.step()
5312 MB torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

For batch size = 1, the above code is OK for first batch, and `out of memory` is reported at loss.backward for second batch.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Do you need the `retain_graph=True`? It doesn't seem like you're using the computation graph again (in the given code).

Comment: Sorry, I have also tried loss.backward(), and OOM still be reported for the second batch.

Comment: did you solve thiis?

Answer (score 0):

To expand slightly on @akshayk07 's answer, you should change the loss line to `loss.backward()` retaining the loss graph requires storing additional information about the model gradient, and is only really useful if you need to backpropogate multiple losses through a single graph. By default, pytorch automatically clears the graph after a single loss value is backpropogated to free up memory. For more on `retain_graph` see [What does the parameter retain_graph mean in the Variable's backward() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774641/what-does-the-parameter-retain-graph-mean-in-the-variables-backward-method). As a rule of thumb, you should only make a `backward()` call with `retain_graph = True` if you plan to make another `backward()` call without `retain_graph = False` on the same batch.

Likely the `empty_cache` operation does not recognize that the loss graph -allocated memory is no longer needed, so it does not free this memory after each batch. Retaining these graphs will quickly fill up the GPU memory.

Comment: I use retain_graph=True because I tried loss.backward() twice for the first batch data. For the second time, an error is reported: Trying to backward through the graph a second time ... Thus, I use loss.backward(retain_graph). However, even using loss.backward(), OOM is reported for the second batch size. It make me crazy.