# Accumulating gradients for a larger batch size with PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

In order to mimick a larger batch size, I want to be able to accumulate gradients every N batches for a model in PyTorch, like:

```
def train(model, optimizer, dataloader, num_epochs, N):
     for epoch_num in range(1, num_epochs+1):
         for batch_num, data in enumerate(dataloader):
             ims = data.to('cuda:0') 
             loss = model(ims)
             loss.backward()
             if batch_num % N == 0:
                 optimizer.step()
                 optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)
```

For this approach do I need to add the flag `retain_graph=True`, i.e.

```
loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
```

In this manner, are the gradients per each backward call simply summed per each parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `retain_graph=True` if you want to make multiple backward passes over the same computational graph, making use of the intermediate results from a single forward pass. This would have been the case, for instance, if you called `loss.backward()` multiple times after computing `loss` once, or if you had multiple losses from different parts of the graph to backpropagate from (a good explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47174709/5987698)).

In your case, for each forward pass, you backpropagate exactly once. So you don't need to store the intermediate results from the computational graph once the gradients are computed.

In short:

- *Intermediate outputs* in the graph are cleared after a backward pass, unless explicitly preserved using `retain_graph=True`.
- *Gradients* accumulate by default, unless explicitly cleared using `zero_grad`.

Comment: Very clear, thanks for the help! To be clear though, "accumulate" means sum?

Comment: @IntegrateThis Yes.